# Can't get content of div tag using XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get the content of a `<div>` tag. Using Safari and Firefox, I got the xpath of the data I want to get.

The div tag is:

```
<div class="RoundRobinTable-cell RoundRobinTable-cell--center">​16 - 4​</div>​
```

And the xpath (according to Safari and Firefox)

```
//*[@id=\"roundrobin\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div
```

My goal is to get the `16 - 4` from that div tag. However, when I tried to verify the xpath using console in Safari, it gives me the whole div tag instead of 16 - 4. The following is my code for C# (which doesn't work).

```
var url = "https://worldcup.playoverwatch.com/en-us/";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmldoc = web.Load(url);
string xpath = "//*[@id=\"roundrobin\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div";
var node = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
string innerResult = node.InnerHtml;
Console.WriteLine(innerResult);
```

1. How can I get the correct string?
2. Is there a way to make this more general? As it can be seen from the link, next to country, there are 2 parts, GR and MR. Let's say I have a string in my app that is the country name (which perfectly matches the name in the website). How can I get the GR and MR values for that country string? Without writing specific xpath and/or things?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using absolute path. try below relative xpath :

```
//div[@class='RoundRobinTable-cell RoundRobinTable-cell--center']
```